# Primefaces serenity theme menu tag is not rendered

Tags: primefaces, taglib

All the css and javascript from serenity premium theme is working as expected but when we try to insert the aside menu the menu items doesn't show and the tag `<pm:menu>` is without anything inside. We did all the configuration based on the documentation of serenity theme, but this specific taglib is not working as you can see in these images:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XllJz.png),
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omr8C.png).
We are using SpringBoot 1.5.7 and Joinfaces(Primefaces 6.1)

Comment: The tags are not rendered. Component suites not being rendered can have multiple causes but most likely you either don't have the namespace corresponding to the pm: prefix not declared or the component jar is not added. Both are in the documentation, so please try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your image, the tag is not rendered. Component suites not being rendered can have multiple causes but most likely you either

- Don't have the namespace corresponding to the pm: prefix not declared (ps in the documentation but that is not important as long as the declaration and prefix match)
- Or the component/theme jar is not added.

(or both)

Both are mentioned in the documentation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, we were missing the theme.jar, actually it is with another name and they did not insert in the documentation. To complement your answer and help another people, just follow this video: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11hn3e1e24bg0ro/import_poseidon_layout_to_your_project.mp4?dl=0)